# Does the AdInsterstitialAd no longer work with iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, interstitial

I have an iPad application where I have integrated the AdInsterstitialAd but it looks like the delegate method:
 `-(void)interstitialAdDidUnload`
 is no longer called when closing the ad in iOS 7. I wanted to know if anyone else has experienced this issue or has found away around this? The unload method is important for me because that is when I want to resume my app's timers (the app pauses itself while the ad is displayed).

I have looked on Apple's website and haven't found anything useful and their current InterstitialAd sample has the same issue.

Comment: Of course I find the answer as soon as I post a question.  And apparently I can't answer my own question for a few more hours so ill post the answer here for now:
There's another method you can use

    – interstitialAdActionDidFinish:

The unload doesnt seem to work in iOS 7 but for iOS 7 of earlier you can use this method instead. According to the documentation however, the unload method is required so I think something still is wrong on Apple's side.

Comment: If there sample has the same issue, file a bug report. How are you presenting the ad? One of the old methods of presenting has been deprecated in iOS7.

Comment: Still the same with iOS 8.0. - (void)presentFromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController appears to be deprecated in documentation, but issues no warning when compiling in iOS8. It is also used by Apple's demo ADGame. This demo is broken and does not resume a new game when needed (sometimes it takes 5 min util the method is called): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdInterstitialSuite/Introduction/Intro.html